# OpenCV - I need to insert color image into black and white image and

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

I insert black and white image into color image with this code and it is ok:

```
face_grey = cv.cvtColor(face, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
for row in range(0, face_grey.shape[0]):
  for column in range(face_grey.shape[1]):
    img_color[row + 275][column + 340] = face_grey[row][column]
plt.imshow(img_color)
```

but, when i try to insert color image into black and white image with this code, i get error:

```
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
for row in range(0, face.shape[0]):
  for column in range(face.shape[1]):
    img_gray[row + 275][column + 340] = face[row][column]
plt.imshow(img_gray)
```

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen? do you expect the color insert to be turned into grayscale? or do you expect the grayscale base image to automatically convert to color? -- learn about numpy slicing. your loops need to disappear. they're wasteful. -- please take the [tour], then review [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: I need to insert a color image inside a black and white image, so that the color image remains in color. When I insert a black and white image into a color one, everything works...

Comment: you said that already. I gave you two options of potential behavior. which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colour image needs 3 channels to represent red, green and blue components.

A greyscale image has only a single channel - grey.

You cannot put a 3-channel image in a 1-channel image any more than you can put a 3-pin plug in a single hole socket.

You need to promote your grey image to 3 identical channels first:

```
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Example:

```
# Make grey background, i.e. 1 channel
background = np.full((200,300), 127, dtype=np.uint8)

# Make small colour overlay, i.e. 3 channels
color = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100,100,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Upgrade background from grey to BGR, i.e. 1 channel to 3 channels
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Check its new shape
print(background.shape)       # prints (200, 300, 3)

# Paste in small coloured image
background[10:110, 180:280] = color
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A color image has the shape (n,m,3) for the three color channels rgb.
A gray scale image has the shame (n,m,1) as the color information is thrown away.
The error happens in this line:

```
img_gray[row + 275][column + 340] = face[row][column]
```

img_gray[row+275][column + 340] expects only one value because img_gray has the a shape (height, width, 1).
face[row][column] has a shape (3,)

You would see that if you do the following:

```py
print(f"{ img_gray[row+275][column + 340].shape} and {face[row][column].shape}")
```